# Wordpress change locale for translation

Tags: php, wordpress, locale

I'm trying to change the language of my website by changing the locale with a filter.

My functions.php :

```
function change_locale_lang($langa) {

    error_log('a : ' . $langa);

    if($langa == 1) return 'en_US';
    elseif($langa == 2) return 'fr_FR';
}

add_filter('locale', 'change_locale_lang', 10);
```

On my template :

```
<?php change_locale_lang(1); ?>
```

The function is well called but 5 times badly and 1 time good !

My debug.log :

```
[08-Dec-2017 11:10:09 UTC] a : fr_FR
[08-Dec-2017 11:10:09 UTC] a : fr_FR
[08-Dec-2017 11:10:09 UTC] a : fr_FR
[08-Dec-2017 11:10:09 UTC] a : 1
[08-Dec-2017 11:10:09 UTC] a : fr_FR
[08-Dec-2017 11:10:09 UTC] a : fr_FR
```

I checked all my templates, the `change_locale_lang()` is called only one time.

It works when I just do `return 'fr_FR'` but not with the code above.

Comment: _Why_ would you try and do that via a filter? The language should be determined by the URL.

Comment: How ? Didn't find it. I use translation like `_e('text', 'theme');`

Comment: Well do you have an actual multi-language site set up ...? (The proper way that’s supposed to be done in WordPress I mean.)

Comment: You mean have different templates for each language ?

Comment: No, of course not ... using the translation functions in your templates is the way to go. But you must have set up your WP site itself to be multilingual to begin with ... how have you done that? (If not at all yet, then that’s where you need to start your research.)

Comment: Is it a way to set up multilingual without a plugin ?